# Surface with bounded torsion propery

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $S$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with the following property:

There is  a uniform constant $M$ such that for every Frenet curve $\gamma(t)$, contained in $S$,   $| \tau(t) | \leq M$, for all t, where $\tau$ is the torsion. Does this imply that $S$ is  a part of a  plane?

And  what  would  be  a  possible  generalization of the  above for a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

The motivation and comment:

We do not assume that $S$ is compact. Even in the compact case $S^{2}$, there is  a Frenet curve $\gamma :(0, \infty) \rightarrow S^{2}$ such that $\tau(t)$ is  unbounded. The reason: a necessary and sufficient condition for that a regular curve $\gamma$ lies on $S^{2}$ is that the pair $(\kappa, \tau)$, curvature and torsion, satisfies in certain differential equation. see Elements of diff geometry by A. Pressley.
It can be easily shown that this differential equation has a solution which $\tau$ is  unbounded. On the other hand for every smooth functions $\kappa(t), \tau(t)$, there is  a Frenet curve for which the curvature and torsion are $\kappa (t), \tau (t) $, respectively . So there is  a Frenet curve in $S^{2}$ which torsion is unbounded.

Comment: This isn't a research question.  The answer is no, and there are elementary examples.

Comment: could you please give an example

Comment: What is a "Frennet curve''? (By the way, you probably mean "Frenet").

Comment: Yes Frenet curve, a curve with nonzero curvature

Comment: Actually, the correct answer is 'Yes, such a (connected) surface $S$ must be part of a plane'.  This follows from the classical formula (easily derivable using moving frames) that expresses the torsion $\tau$ of a curve $\gamma$ on a surface $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ in terms of the second fundamental form and its first covariant derivative, $\rho$, and $\dot\rho$, where $\rho$ is the *geodesic* curvature of the curve on the surface.  From this formula, one sees that, unless the second fundamental form vanishes identically, there cannot be such a bound on $\tau$.

Comment: I think I see a non-formulaic argument for Bryant's answer.  If you have non-zero 2nd fundamental form, take a curve in the surface through that point whose tangent vector points in a non-zero 2nd fundamental form direction. Make the curve "wiggle" with high frequency as it passes through that point, this forces the curvature to be always non-zero and rapidly alternate from one side of the curve to the other, so the torsion can be made large by making the frequency large.  I still don't see it as an MO question. But I agree my initial comment was wrong on the "no" point.