# Sphere with bounded curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, isoperimetric-problems

Let $V$ be a body in $\mathbb{R}^3$ bounded by a smooth sphere with principal curvatures at most 1 (by absolute value).
Is it true that
$$\mathop{\rm vol} V\ge \mathop{\rm vol} B,$$
where $B$ denotes the unit ball?

**Comments**

- I heard this question from Dima Burago.
- In $\mathbb{R}^2$ an analogous statement follows from the [Pestov–Ionin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pestov%E2%80%93Ionin_theorem).
- One might think that $V$ contains a copy of $B$, but this is not true; an example was constructed by Lagunov (Sibirsk. Mat. Zh. 1961)

**Postscript.** There is a closed surface with normal curvatures at most 1 that bounds volume arbitrarily close to $\tfrac{22 }3\cdot\pi-2\cdot\pi^2\approx 3.3$.
This volume is swapped by rotating the
hatched figure in $2\times2$ square around its lower side.

[image]

This volume is smaller than the volume of unit ball which is $\tfrac43\cdot\pi\approx 4.2$.

However, the surface is homeomorphic to the *sphere with two handles*.
(It is an optimized version of one of Lagunov's examples.)
I tried to optimize the spherical example and was not able to get below $\tfrac43\cdot\pi$.
Maybe one can prove that it is impossible, but most likely it is going to be tedious.

Comment: Any chance you could describe Lagunov’s example?

Comment: @DeaneYang It can be obtained by thinkening Bing's house. A slightly simpler example is discussed in our book; see pp 107--108 https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.11814.pdf

Comment: This remind me of a question I posed in my course of "differential geometry" in midterm as follows: Let $\gamma$ be closed curve included in unit circle prove that there is a point whose curvature is $\geq 1$

Comment: Oh Thank you for link to Pestov Inon theorem. I was not aware of this theorem. When I posed this question for my student  in midterm examination of undergraduate differential geometry I was not aware of this theorem so it was a spantaneous observation.

Comment: Any way my previous post below has similar flavour https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152411/surface-with-bounded-torsion-propery

Comment: Does "bounded by a smooth sphere" mean that $V$ is a compact $3$-manifold with boundary and $\partial V$ is topologically a sphere?

Comment: @OtisChodosh yes

Comment: would that be an absurd try an argument along the lines of volume monotonicity formulae for the MCF? For instance, considering the MCF of the boundary on $V$ as well as doing the same for the boundary of the ball and then checking which kind of relation we can infer from the ambients, that is, from $B$ and $V$?

Comment: @L.F.Cavenaghi I could not imagine that it is working if $V$ is nonconvex (which is the only interesting case).