# Simplified Bing's house

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

[Bing's house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_with_two_rooms) is an example of contractible 2-complex in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
One may think that it is a surface without boundary that has two types of singularities: *tripod curves* — curves where three pieces of surface come together and *quadrapod  vertices* — vertices where 4 curves and 6 pieces of surface come together.
Formally speaking, Bing's house has the same local structure as the 2-skeleton of 4-cube.

The singularities of Bing's house look like this:

[image: 1-skeleton of Bing's house]

It has 2 quadrapod vertices connected by 4 tripod curves (pair of loops and a pair of parallel edges).
Bing's house is this graph with 3 discs attached.

> Is there a simpler design? (Or another reasonably simple design)

I am interested in surfaces with the same type singularities.

*(Motivated by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/425509).)*

Comment: If Q is the number of quadrapod vertices and T is the number of tripod curves then 2Q=T necessarily, because 6Q-3T will be the Euler characteristic of the boundary of the two-dimensional stratum.

Comment: (This was assuming that none of the curves is a circle, I mean that each of the curves ends at two quadrapod vertices (which might be equal).)

Comment: @TomGoodwillie well it is simply because all vertices have degree 2, right?

Comment: I wonder, is it Bing's?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Say, maybe 3 vertices are sufficient, or maybe  4 vertices with different design --- that is my question.

Comment: You are probably aware of the dunce hat?

Comment: I believe that the dunce hat does not have the desired vertex link about its unique “vertex” (point of “order” greater than three). That is, the dunce cap is not a special spine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “abalone shell” is the simplest contractible, non-collapsible two-complex embedding in three-space.  This is because it has a single “vertex”. For a picture, see Figure 3 of Matveev’s [article](https://archive.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/id/eprint/2389/2/preprint_1998_67.pdf).

By the way, Bing’s house has two vertices, not four (as suggested by your figure). See Figure 4 of Matveev’s article.

Comment: right, thank you, I will correct my question